# Looking for replacement diode V6 88

Tags: identification, zener, tvs

I'm guessing this is either a Zener or TVS diode. All I can see is 'V6 88' i can't find any info anywhere about it. My ECU in my bus has cooked 2 of these, side by side, so I guess they need replacing first. Thanks for any help.

[image: center of pic]

Comment: If the parts are connecting the "bus" maybe you might add, which bus that is. It could help us to get the context for this device. And what's ECU an abbreviation for?

Answer (score 1):

That is a 1 amp 600 volt diode D1F60 .

Comment: Bezev - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However in the [D1F60 datasheet](https://www.shindengen.co.jp/tools/pdf_generator/?category=di&lang=en&no=D1F60), I couldn't find any listing of the possible top markings to confirm that those codes "V6 88" are for that *specific* diode. Do you have a link or other reference to confirm the identification with those top codes? You can always [edit] your answer to add references. Thanks.

Comment: Check this pdf to confirm the marking : http://www.ineltro.ch/media/downloads/SAAItem/23/23248/ac1167d4-2a96-446c-97cc-cabb24a7344f.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could find: [Toshiba 1SV313](https://www2.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/ToshibaAmericaElectronics_1357-43188-1209510.pdf)

[image]

The '88' could be a production lot number.